# Two dictionaries - how to merge?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to to put some calculated network details in one dictionary and I have these two dictionaries:

```
    "netmk": {
        "host_A": {
            "netmask": "255.255.255.240"
        },
        "host_B": {
            "netmask": "255.255.255.128"
        }
    }


    "netip": {
        "host_A": {
            "ip": "192.168.10.1"
        },
        "host_B": {
            "ip": "192.168.20.1"
        }
    }
```

I want to make such structure:

```
     "net": {
        "host_A": {
            "ip": 192.168.10.1
            "netmask": "255.255.255.240"                  
        },
        "host_B": {
            "ip": 192.168.20.1
            "netmask": "255.255.255.128"
        }
    }
```

How to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Merging dictionaries in ansible/jinja2 is made with the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries). For the below oneliner example, I added your sample data to the file `so_data.yml`

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ netmk | combine(netip, recursive=true) }}" -e @so_data.yml
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": {
        "host_A": {
            "ip": "192.168.10.1",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.240"
        },
        "host_B": {
            "ip": "192.168.20.1",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.128"
        }
    }
}
```